# Как сделать адаптивный svg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, адаптивная-верстка

Необходимо сделать адаптивный `SVG`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении размеров изображения (или `viewport`-а), дочерние элементы `SVG` перемещались и перестраивались (как в адаптивной вёрстке HTML).

Как сделать такой `SVG`?

[image: Пример-схема]

Comment: Это да, но вопрос не в реализации самого принципа, а в том, как это сделать с помощью одного файла svg и/или xml в нем.

Comment: Планировалось реализовать возможность загружать баннер (на сайт) единым изображением (легко загружаемым), а уже в изображении настраивать некую адаптивность...

Comment: Сложно назвать задачу невозможной ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Была надежда на svg и его внутреннюю разметку, но увы, похоже =)

Comment: Да, с разметкой такое точно не "прокатит", можно попробовать с `JS`. Я могу сделать конкурс для этого вопроса, чтобы больше людей смогли заметить этот вопрос, и, в будущем кто-то может и даст ответ

Comment: Я тут новичок совсем =) и с функционалом еще не полностью знакома (это я про "конкурс"). Но думаю, если найдется ответ на этот вопрос, то он сможет принести пользу - так что буду признательна!

Comment: Ознакомиться с конкурсами вы можете здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Боюсь, в svg такое вряд ли найдётся, ибо не для того он делался

Comment: @andreymal, в `SVG` такого нет, раньше был `textArea`, но увы он был предназначен для переноса текста, а в скором времени его искоренили. Вполне возможно есть какой-то плагин, но это не точная информация

Answer (score 20):

Можно создать "адаптивное" svg-изображение. Для этого нужно прописать внутри него css-медиазапросы и двигать элементы через `transform`.
Пример изображения:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200px" height="200px" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <style>
    circle,
    rect{
      stroke-width:2px;
      fill:none;
      stroke:orange;
    }
    @media (max-width: 120px){
      circle{
        transform:translateX(50px);
      }
      rect{
        transform:translate(-60px,80px);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="34" />
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="80" height="60" />
</svg>
```

Далее вставляем его на страницу(использовал data:url т.к. SO не хочет принимать svg картинки и ссылки без https, но это тот же самый svg):

```js
$('input').on('input',function(){
  $('img').width(this.value);
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:top;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" />

<label for="controller">Тут задавать ширину для картинки</label>
<input id="controller" type="number" min="70" max="500" step="5" />
```

Comment: Наверняка единственный способ, тоже так делал. Но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли вообще какой-то плагин для этого.

Comment: @Arthur , не знаю. Надо подождать, может кто и предложит. Было бы интересно, если и контуры менять можно было.

Comment: 50 баллов заслуживает этот ответ, так как самый первый , да и 2 подобных ответа по сути ничем не отличаются.

Comment: @Arthur отличаются - так как водном из ответов нету jquery .....без которого не будет работать адаптивность, я вообще смотрю многие любят на js решения ...

Comment: @Arthur ты не понял меня ...ты написал что другие ответы похожие ..я проверил тот ответ что ты выбрал и так же другие ответы .. и  не увидел сходства ...это не сарказм ...а просто сходства нету ...хотя мне лампочки

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а там по сути `jquery` не нужен, лишь для регулировки размеров

Comment: @Arthur я согласен

Answer (score 11):

Набросал пример кода на чистом svg и разумеется здесь мы не увидим как меняется расположение svg объектов то привожу пример в: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oPBzvw?editors=1000 в котором изменение положения объектов произойдёт при разрешении меньше 600px.

> что бы увидеть здесь адаптивность svg надо открыть пример кода на всю страницу а сжать сам браузер до менее 600px

img preview :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<svg viewbox="0 250 200" id="svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      #svg{
        width:210px;
        height:100px;
      }
      #rect{
        width:50px;
        height:40px;
        fill:red;
        x:20px;
        y:30px;
      }
      #circle{
        cx:150px;
        cy:50px;
        fill:blue;
        r:40px;
      }
      
      @media (max-width:600px){
        #svg{
          width:200px;
          height:140px;
        }
        #rect{
        width:50px;
        height:40px;
        fill:red;
        x:70px;
        y:5px;
          fill:blue;
      }
      #circle{
        cx:95px;
        cy:90px;
        fill:blue;
        r:40px;
        fill:red;
      }    
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect id="rect"></rect>
  <circle id="circle"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8):

Вариант на `JS` (подобно `flex-wrap` в `CSS`):

```js
const $d = document;

let rects = $d.getElementsByTagName('rect');

const arrangement = e => {
  let windowWidth = $d.documentElement.clientWidth;
  let offset_x = 20;
  let offset_y = 20;
  let next_offset_y = offset_y;
  let offset = 20;

  let maxH = 0;
  let maxW = 0;

  for (let i = 0, len = e.length; i < len; i++) {
    let w = parseInt(getComputedStyle(e[i]).width);
    let h = parseInt(getComputedStyle(e[i]).height);

    if (h > maxH) {
      maxH = h;
    }

    if (w > maxW) {
      maxW = w;
    }

    if (maxW + w + offset_x + offset + offset + offset > windowWidth) {
      set(e, i, offset_x, offset_y);
      offset_y += offset + next_offset_y;
      offset_x = 20;
      maxH = h;
    } else {
      set(e, i, offset_x, offset_y);
      offset_x += w + offset;
      next_offset_y = maxH;
    }
  }
};

const set = (e, i, offset_x, offset_y) => {
  e[i].setAttribute('x', offset_x);
  e[i].setAttribute('y', offset_y);
}

arrangement(rects);
window.onresize = function(e) {
  arrangement(rects);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper svg {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: hsl(10, 0%, 70%);
}

.wrapper svg .main-area rect {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.125rem;
}

.wrapper svg .main-area rect.rect1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 25px;
}

.wrapper svg .main-area rect.rect2 {
  width: 25px;
  height: 70px;
}

.wrapper svg .main-area rect.rect3 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <g class="main-area" fill="hsl(50,100%,70%)">
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect class='rect3'/>
      <rect class='rect3'/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect class='rect1'/>
      <rect/>
      <rect class='rect2'/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect class='rect2'/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
      <rect/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: как обычно не работает в Edge и в Firefox

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, сейчас исправлю, нужно вынести, в атрибуты `width` & `height`

Comment: кстати тот пример про рыбий глаз - посмотри я там ссылку скинул

Comment: Артур а теперь вообще не работает ...т.е  блоки появились но они стоят в ряд … хотя Edge поддерживает flex и так же flex-wrap ….наверное это особенность Edge

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, нужно добавлять отдельно для элементов высоту и ширину, почему-то свойства css не поддерживаются в svg))

Comment: в лисе по прежнему не работает вообще - т.е в Edge частично работает а в Лисе нет

Comment: в svg поддерживается css - как видишь я же в своём примере показал даже медиа запросы в svg - ладно это ерунда всё..  svg всё же не для этого - svg это резина и так

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, не, я про атрибуы

Comment: я ваш пример поместил на toster.ru как [пример](https://toster.ru/q/563920) flex-wrap на js

Comment: @НикитаФаст, принял, буду знать

Answer (score 5):

Это можно сделать, используя любую js библиотеку для работы с SVG.

К примеру я взял [SVG.js](http://svgjs.com/):

Сразу предоставлю [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/zzzoryn/9ve7kh5p/), а ниже код примера:

```js
var draw = SVG('banner');

var bg = draw
          .rect('100%', '100%')
          .attr({ fill: '#ffeb3b' });

var elem1 = draw
            .ellipse(100, 100)
            .attr({ fill: '#f06' });
            
var elem2 = draw
            .rect(150, 100)
            .attr({ fill: '#f06' });

bunnerUpdate();
window.onresize = bunnerUpdate;

function bunnerUpdate() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 400) {
    draw.size(400, 200);
    elem1.move(50, 50);
    elem2.move(200, 50);
  }
  else {
    draw.size('100%', 350);
    elem1.move(window.innerWidth / 2 - 50, 50);
    elem2.move(window.innerWidth / 2 - 75, 200);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: > `Uncaught ReferenceError: SVG is not defined`

Comment: На то и ссылка на рабочий пример, а Вы сразу минусуете. Исправил код, чтоб можно было его выполнить

Comment: не я минус поставил, да и если бы не указал вам на это, вы бы не поменяли, люди бы так и запускали ваш пример с ошибкой

Comment: кстати, по правилам, _ссылка не является ответом_

Answer (score 5):

Удивительно, что все ответы, написанные до меня, не соответствуют условию поставленной задачи. Обратите внимание на то, что нужно отслеживать именно размеры **изображения**:

> Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении размеров ***изображения*** (или viewport-а)

А все 4 ответа, написанные до меня, это вообще не принимают во внимание и отслеживают как один изменение размеров **окна**. Непонятно также почему спустя 4 месяца на это никто не обратил внимания?! Напомнило мне смешную старую **[шутку про разработчиков](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chjrV.png)**.

Но если кому-то всё же нужно откликаться на изменение окна, то изучайте первые 4 ответа и статью по **[ссылке](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)** (она про CSS медиа-запросы такие как `@media (max-width:600px)`).

### Правильное решение

Если переводить слово «адаптивный» на русский язык, то мы получим два слова «приспосабливающийся» и «приспосабливаемый». Окончание «-ийся» всегда подразумевает, что предмет действия сам себя(сокращение -ся в конце) приспособит. А вот «приспосабливаемый» означает что предмет действия будет кем-то(чем-то) приспособлен. К примеру, его приспособит вышестоящее окно - то есть кто-то(что-то), но не он сам.

**Случай, когда это «приспосабливающийся»**

В данном случае этот приспосабливающийся будет наш SVG объект, который будет отслеживать изменения в себе и *приспосабливать себя*. Для этого мы в самом SVG объекте (хотя можно и снаружи) через JavaScript при помощи функции `window.setTimeout` каждые `50 милисекунд` отслеживаем изменения размеров изображения посредством сравнения значения свойства ширины `svg.getAttribute('width')`. И если это значение меняется, то мы меняем расположение прямоугольника, изменяя значения его свойств (или т.н. атрибутов) `x` и `y` при помощи функции `rect.setAttribute();`. Мы также вместо этого можем изменить CSS свойство `transform:translate(...px, ...px);`, обращение к которому в JavaScript выглядит так:

```
rect.style.transform = 'translate(...px, ...px)';
```

Но приводить пример с `transform` нет смысла, т.к. это уже сделали в двух первых примерах.

Также важно заметить, что изменяя размер изображения посредством `svg.setAttribute('width', ...);` мы также должны изменить и размер его `viewBox`-а, ибо иначе будет несоответствие и изображение исказится.

Итак, первый пример / случай:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('#svg');

function changeWidth(obj)
{
    var width = +obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;

    svg.setAttribute('width', width);
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0,0,' + width + ',320');
}
```

```css
body{background:#000}
```

```html
<font color="white">Ширина <s>окна</s> SVG изображения:
<select onchange="changeWidth(this)">
    <option>320</option>
    <option>210</option>
</select> px.</font><br><br>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 320 320" width="320" height="320" style="background:#fff">
<g fill="none" stroke="#f93" stroke-width="3">
    <polygon points="60,10,110,60,60,110,10,60"/>
    <rect id="rect" x="130" y="10" width="180" height="100"/>
</g>
<script type="text/javascript">
var svg = document.querySelector('#svg'),
    rect = svg.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];

(function checkWidth()
{
    var w = +svg.getAttribute('width'); //+ значит перевод из string в integer
    if(w < 211)
    {
        rect.setAttribute('x', 10);
        rect.setAttribute('y', 120)
    }
    else
    {
        rect.setAttribute('x', 130);
        rect.setAttribute('y', 10)
    }
    window.setTimeout(checkWidth, 50)
})()
</script>
</svg>
```

**Случай, когда это «приспосабливаемый»**

Этот случай более сложный для данной задачи, т.к. SVG – это векторное изображение и в нём для каждой точки уже должны быть определённые координаты. И хотя решение, когда свойства прямоугольника изменяются извне, можно было бы с натяжкой назвать «приспосабливаемый», но это всё же неправильно, т.к. мы изменяем его свойства местоположения.

Итак, смотрите что я имею ввиду под «приспосабливаемый» SVG (пример, который также решает поставленную задачу):

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('#svg');

function changeWidth(obj)
{
    var size = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text.split(' x ');

    svg.setAttribute('width', size[0]);
    svg.setAttribute('height', size[1]);
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0,0,' + size[0] + ','+size[1]);
}
```

```css
body{background:#000}
```

```html
<font color="white">Размер SVG изображения:
<select onchange="changeWidth(this)">
    <option value="">320 x 120</option>
    <option value="">200 x 240</option>
</select> px.</font><br><br>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 320 120" width="320" height="120" style="background:#fff">
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
        <polygon points="60,10,110,60,60,110,10,60" fill="none" stroke="#f93" stroke-width="3"/>
    </svg>
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 120">
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="180" height="100" fill="none" stroke="#f93" stroke-width="3"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Обратите внимание на то, как во внутренних SVG изображениях выставлены свойства **[`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)**, которые и способствуют тому, чтобы расположить наши изображения таким образом. Также здесь важны свойства ширины и высоты, которые во втором внутреннем SVG установлены в `100%`. И используемые вместе они действуют таким образом, что наш второй внутренний SVG выстраивается либо крайне справа, либо крайне снизу.

Вот что я называю здесь «приспосабливаемый» SVG, т.к. нигде в коде ничего не меняется (не указывается) в зависимости от размера изображения как в случае с «приспосабливающийся» SVG. Всё, что мы делаем – это изменяем **только** размеры изображения **и ничего более**.